# Need a string JSON Validator

Tags: c#, .net, json

I'm using newtonsoft's JSON.Net and loving every minute of it.

However, I am using `JObject.Parse(jsonString)` to grab a JToken from a response string.  If I send invalid JSON, I get an exception.  I can catch the exception, but I would like to, be able to test the string first before sending it to Parse.

Maybe something akin to `JObject.TryParse()` (which doesn't exist).

I'd even take 
  bool ValidJson(string)

I know there's JSONLint out there, but I would really like to keep the external calls to a minimum.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to write a function which calls `JObject.Parse` and returns false if it throws a `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException`.

Comment: Return `true` for this invalid `JSON`: `{A:{"B": 1}}`

Answer (score 3):

Use JContainer.Parse(str) method to check if the str is a valid Json. If this throws exception then it is not a valid Json.

```
JObject.Parse - Can be used to check if the string is a valid Json object
JArray.Parse - Can be used to check if the string is a valid Json Array
JContainer.Parse - Can be used to check for both Json object & Array
```

Answer (score 0):

*A working code snippet*

```
public bool isValidJSON(string json)
{
    try
    {
        JToken token = JObject.Parse(json);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks to [MRAB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/688213/mrab)

Comment: Return `true` for this invalid `JSON`: `{A:{"B": 1}}`

Comment: Since this is a C# method, I the name should be Pascal case, so `IsValidJson`.