# Validate a string to be json or not in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, servicestack

is there any way to validate a string to be json or not ? other than try/catch .

I'm using ServiceStack Json Serializer and couldn't find a method related to validation .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check JSON and XML is valid? c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766974/check-json-and-xml-is-valid-c-sharp)

Comment: that solution uses try/catch . I'm looking for method like TryParse that we have for int,date,... . just to check if string contains a valid json structure or not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make sure that string is Valid JSON using JSON.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977848/how-to-make-sure-that-string-is-valid-json-using-json-net)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably the quickest and dirtiest way is to check if the string starts with **'{'**:

```
public static bool IsJson(string input){ 
    input = input.Trim(); 
    return input.StartsWith("{") && input.EndsWith("}")  
           || input.StartsWith("[") && input.EndsWith("]"); 
}
```

Another option is that you could try using the JavascriptSerializer class:

```
JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
SomeJSONClass = ser.Deserialize<SomeJSONClass >(json);
```

Or you could have a look at JSON.NET:

- http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx
- http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 1):

*A working code snippet*

```
public bool isValidJSON(String json)
{
    try
    {
        JToken token = JObject.Parse(json);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30932433/730807)

Comment: This misses scenarios when the payload is missing a closing } or ] .

Answer (score 0):

You can find a couple of regular expressions to validate JSON over here: [Regex to validate JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583472/regex-to-validate-json)

It's written in PHP but should be adaptable to C#.